# MediaPlayer stops working with error "Event 11 was not found in the queue, already cancelled?"

Tags: android, media-player, android-mediaplayer

My app so far is very simple. Just a button that plays a sound. The problem is that if I press the button too fast, I get an error and the media player no longer responds.

Here's my code.

```
public class Keyboard extends Activity
{
    private MediaPlayer player = null;

    private OnTouchListener listener = new OnTouchListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent e) {
            switch (e.getActionMasked()) {
            case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
                System.out.println("down");
                player.start();
                break;
            case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
                System.out.println("up");
                player.pause();
                break;
            }
            return false;
        }
    };

    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);

        player = MediaPlayer.create(getApplicationContext(),
                R.raw.bloop);
        player.setLooping(true);

        Button foo = (Button)findViewById(R.id.A);
        foo.setOnTouchListener(listener);
    }
}
```

All I'm doing is calling play() when the button is pressed, and calling pause() when the button is let go. Here's a sample of a typical log.

```
I/System.out( 1796): up
I/System.out( 1796): down
I/System.out( 1796): up
I/System.out( 1796): down
I/System.out( 1796): up
W/TimedEventQueue(   38): Event 2 was not found in the queue, already cancelled?
I/System.out( 1796): down
I/System.out( 1796): up
I/System.out( 1796): down
I/System.out( 1796): up
```

As you can see, my debug statements still work after the error, so the OnTouchListener is still working.

Comment: Looks like this has something either to do with [onDestroy being called][1] or maybe the [automatic garbage collector disposing of your player][2].


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7407979/media-player-stops-abruptly-with-a-warning-in-logcat-timedeventqueue33-event
  [2]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4569102/mediaplayer-not-playing-audio-properly

Answer (score 0):

From the error log i.e. `MediaPlayer Event 11 was not found in the queue, already cancelled` is a warning and not an error. Please refer to this [link](http://androidxref.com/4.2.2_r1/xref/frameworks/av/media/libstagefright/TimedEventQueue.cpp#288). Hence, if your `MediaPlayer` is exiting, then there should be some other issue.

This warning is printed when an `event` which was expected to be `triggered` gets removed from the `queue` before it actually triggered. This can happen in multiple cases. For example, in case of `pause`, all player events are cancelled as shown [here](http://androidxref.com/4.2.2_r1/xref/frameworks/av/media/libstagefright/AwesomePlayer.cpp#1137).

In your case, I feel that one of the potential scenario would be thus. `AwesomePlayer` would have triggered an `event` to read the next video frame from the video decoder i.e. `mVideoSource`. In between you pressed `pause` which caused all events to be removed. So when `TimedEventQueue` triggered in this `threadRun` loop, it would observe that this `event` has been removed and hence, the log.